# Punk/emo bands that sound similar to "The World Is a Beautiful Place & I Am No Longer Afraid to Die"?

Tags: similar-artists, punk

I’m just looking for new music to jam to while working. Recently I stumbled upon [TWIABP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Is_a_Beautiful_Place_%26_I_Am_No_Longer_Afraid_to_Die), and I really like the sound. It’s like an emo experimental with spoken word.

Are there any other bands like this, if you were to base the judgement off these 2 songs?

- *[Space exploration to solve an earthly crisis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfxaW7ZGMhU)*
- *[Autotonsorialist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRLAIRmlI9U)*

I really like the sounds and meaning behind the music, plus albums like this where the music all blends into one helps time go by faster. Any ideas?

I already know of [Dads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dads_%28band%29), [Tiny Moving Parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Moving_Parts), [Old Gray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Gray) and Merchant Ships. Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Listening to a few seconds reminded me of Godspeed You! Black Emperor, and according to the TWIABP&IANLATD (kids and their band names these days) bio they are an inspiration. GYBE are totally objectively a lot better too, so check 'em out...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll go give GYBE a listen. Tell me about it though, it's pretty obnoxious to type out their name lol

Comment: Both songs have elements that remind me of postrock bands like Mono or Sigur Ros.  I'd suggest picking a couple of their songs on YT and see if they resonate with you.

Answer (score 1):

I have been listening to the band you mentioned and looked at some spotify recommendations and stuff and the most repetitive bands that came up were sorority noise, foxing, and tigers jaw. Hope this helps!